# surf() in Matlab showing only two colors instead of multiple colors

Tags: matlab, plot, surf

I am using the following lines of code to plot:

```
nthTheta=1;
gammaSurf=reshape(gamma(:,nthTheta,:),size(gamma,1),size(gamma,3));
figure
[spatial_lag,temporal_lag]=meshgrid(distance,4:4:12);
surf(gammaSurf,spatial_lag',temporal_lag')
colorbar
xlabel('Spatial Lag','Fontweight','Bold')
ylabel('Temporal Lag','Fontweight','Bold')
zlabel('\gamma (h,t)','Fontweight','Bold')
title('Spatiotemporal Empirical Variogram','Fontweight','Bold')
```

The `gammaSurf` matrix has following values which shows its values are changing:

[image]

I get the following plot with only two colors instead of multiple variation in colors:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong because of which I am not getting a plot with multiple color variation which I expect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [shading](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/shading.html) to be interpolated:

```
shading(gca,'interp');
```

should do the trick.

Actually, it looks like you've got the arguments to `surf` in the wrong order.  If you want the z-axis to apply to the gammasurf values, that needs to be the third argument.

```
surf(spatial_lag',temporal_lag',gammasurf);
```

One last suggestion:  If you indeed did mean for `gammasurf` to be the x-values but you wanted those to be what define the color, use that as the 4th argument (`C`):

```
surf(gammasurf,spatial_lag',temporal_lag',gammasurf);
```

Now the surface will be oriented like in the image, but with colors varying with the x-value rather than the z-value.

Comment: Thanks tmpearce!! You are right, I had got the arguments in wrong order i.e. the `gammaSurf` should have been the third argument.